# How to encode and decode the uploaded file using input type file

Tags: javascript, encoding, base64

I have created multiple file upload option for user. I want to encode and decode the uploaded file... Here i write the program for convert the image to base64 string... How to encode as well as decode the file using base64.

My Code is

```
<html>
<body>

<input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL();" multiple />
<div id="imgTest"></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function encodeImageFileAsURL() {

    var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
    if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
      var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

      var fileReader = new FileReader();

      fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
        var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64

        var newImage = document.createElement('img');
        newImage.src = srcData;

        document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML = newImage.outerHTML;
        alert("Converted Base64 version is " +          document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML);
        var reslut =    document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML; 
        console.log("Converted Base64 version is " +reslut);

      }
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In console i print the encoded value of file... How to use console output for decode purpose.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: console output encode value. base64 like Base64 version is <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABQAAAAMgCAYAAAB8mM/7AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAA.....

Comment: How to store the encoded value in variable. And again i decode the store value show only thumbnail of uploaded image

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.atob(base64string)`,i think it is a utf8 string of a blob object